# Optimize a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables in my DB: user, log1, log2, log3 and log4.
Each log saves data about the user (log1 is logins log, etc.) - each log has UserID and CreateTime and LogID as his columns.

I want to create a query that is fast enough, that will show me the number of times each log has this user id. something like:

```
select u.UserID, Count(log1.CreateTime) as l1, ... Count(log4.CreateTime) as l4 
from users u left join log1 on log1.UserID = u.UserID left join ...
group by u.UserID
```

The problem is that this query take too much time.

Can anyone help me optimize my query?

Comment: Review the execution plan for your query to determine where things are slow.  My guess is that you need some indexes somewhere.

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Sql Server, MySql e.g.

Comment: @HasanBİNBOĞA mysql.

Answer (score 2):

For this query:

```
select u.UserID, Count(log1.CreateTime) as l1, ... Count(log4.CreateTime) as l4 
from users u left join
     log1
     on log1.UserID = u.UserID left join ...
group by u.UserID
```

You want indexes on the "log" tables:  `log1(UserId)`, etc.

However, I don't think this is what you are really looking for.  With the same indexes, you should use correlated subqueries:

```
select u.*,
       (select count(*) from log1 where log1.UserID = u.UserID) as log1_cnt,
       . . .
from users u;
```

(This assumes that the creation date/time column is never `NULL`.)

This is better for several reasons:

- It does the correct counts.  Your version produces the same count (or 0) for the four columns.
- This does not create an intermediate Cartesian product for a given user for the records from the four tables.
- This does not use a `group by` in the outer query.
- Indexes can be used for the correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to get statistics of your log records.

We have log databases, insert about 1 millon records per day. We create statistic database and add trigger on log tables for insert. So we update or insert statistic record for each log insert.